# org.json.JSONException: Value <html of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

i want to make a registration activity in my app. and i want to connect to the php file that reside on the server and that connects to a database on the same server and insert the data in the database.

**RegisterActivity.java**

```
package com.tejas.paras.ourapp;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ProgressDialog pDialog;

JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
EditText name1;
EditText email1;
EditText password1;
EditText phone1;
InputStream is=null;
String result=null;
String line=null;
int code;
String name, email, phone, password;
Button btnreg;
private static String url_create_product ="http://www.painnation.esy.es/create_product.php";
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }

    name1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    email1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    password1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText6);
    phone1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText8);

    // Create button
    btnreg = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    btnreg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        name = name1.getText().toString();
         email = email1.getText().toString();
         password = password1.getText().toString();
         phone = phone1.getText().toString();

        insert();
     }
});
}


public void insert()
    {
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phone", phone));

        try
        {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("URL TO PHP FILE ON SERVER");
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
            Log.e("pass 1", "connection success ");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("Fail 1", e.toString());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid IP Address",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        try
        {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader
                    (new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
            Log.e("pass 2", "connection success ");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("Fail 2", e.toString());
        }

        try
        {

            JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result);
            code=(json_data.getInt("code"));

            if(code==1)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Inserted Successfully",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Sorry, Try Again",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("Fail 3", e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

**insert.php**

```
<?php
$host='HOST_NAME';
$uname='USER_NAME';
$pwd='PASSWORD';
$db='DATABASE_NAME';

$con = mysqli_connect("$host","$uname","$pwd","$db");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}


$name=$_REQUEST['name'];
$email=$_REQUEST['email'];
$password=$_REQUEST['password'];
$phone=$_REQUEST['phone'];

$flag['code']=0;


if($r = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO register VALUES('','$name', '$email', '$password',$phone)"))
{
    $flag['code']=1;
}

print(json_encode($flag));
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

[Pic of the error in log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vNIh.png)

how to solve this error or any other code by which I can insert the data to database.

Thank You.

Comment: You're echo'ing `hi` inside your `if`, which is not valid json at that point... Also: Don't use `mysql_*` functions, they're deprecated (and actually removed in PHP7). Further more: You're wide open to SQL Injections. Where are `$email`,`$password` and `$phone` coming from? They're undefined variables in your PHP script.

Comment: Just Try to print response.

Comment: Your php script actually prints `Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in [...]/insert.php on line 7
{"code":0}` - This is not parsable JSON.

Comment: your api is not returning json infact it is not returning anything at all so response is getting html page.

Comment: bro, i have made the changes but now also same error, and can you provide a good link to understand json.

Comment: if your connection is working fine this will print the {"code":1}.. tested

Answer (score 0):

First make String request then call json object because your response is in string format so try this.